# Правильно ли выражение "без ничего"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Часто слышу и от интеллигентных людей, например:

*Да я буду пить чай **без ничего.***

Или вот в Нацкорпусе нашёл из "Идиота" Достоевского:

*― Возьмёте как есть, без ничего! ― Возьму, Настасья Филипповна...*

Да и вообще в Нацкорпусе 122 примера он находит. Получается, это совершенно нормальное литературное выражение?

Comment: Просторечия в устах персонажей из произведений классиков доказывают только отсутствие аргументов у тех, кто приводит их в обоснование нормативности таких выражений. Не придавайте значения таким "аргументам".

Comment: @Alex_ander: что скажете по поводу ответа grizzly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примеры из нацкорпуса ни о чем не говорят. Даже из Достоевского. Язык литературы и литературный язык – разные вещи. Конечно, это не соответствует литературной норме, но так говорят.

Comment: Спасибо, Niemand!

Comment: Не согласен. Как раз очень о многом говорят примеры из классики. Разумеется не о том, что форма нормативная, а то, что она характеризует героев...

Comment: А мы здесь как раз о нормативности.

Comment: Не, это Вы о чем-то своем. А вот я - да, как раз о нормативности.  Очень много говорят о нормативности такие выражения, надо только смотреть, **кто** говорит, и не путать Достоевского с героями Достоевского и разговоры **о** нормативности с **декларациями нормативности**. У Вас же - какие-то малопонятные сентенции "насчет литературного языка" и "языка литературы" .Хорошо, если Вы просто неудачно выразились, забыв термин ""прямая речь", но скорее всего просто  запутались.  .

Comment: Если вы не видите разницы между литературным языком и языком литературы (художественной), то что ж... Просвещайтесь. А прямая речь тут совсем ни при чём.

Answer (score 3):

***Выражение, на мой взгляд, неправильное.*** В художественной литературе оно, конечно, встречается, это неудивительно. Правильно ***ни с чем.***

Предлог ***без*** имеет значение ***"отсутствие чего-то"***, но само  ***что-то*** предполагает наличие, должно указывать на предмет, обозначать предмет или быть отвлечённым существительным: ***без слёз, без жизни, без любви.***

Местоимение "ничего" - это полное отсутствие всего, ноль. Поэтому предлог без не может употребляться с таким местоимением. Смысловая тавтология получается.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина!

Answer (score 2):

Ничего просторечного в выражении **без ничего** я не нахожу. Хотя признаю, что этот миф широко распространён. Единственный известный мне способ решать подобные споры — обратиться к словарям.

**Словарь современного русского литературного языка, том 7, 1958 г.**

> **Без ничего**.
>   Однажды Печорин отправился с Максимом Максимычем на охоту за кабаном. Однако ж, после полудня, они без ничего подъезжали к
>   крепости. Бел. «Герой наш. врем.» Лермонтова.
>   Порфирий
>   Владимирович сидит за столом один и как-то вяло хлебает пустой суп (он
>   терпеть не мог **суп без ничего**).

[Академический словарь Кузнецова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)

> **Без ничего**, в зн. нареч. 1. Ничего не имея, не приобретя. Поехали за грибами, вернулись без ничего. Идти в гости без ничего. -2. в
>   функц. сказ. Ничем не сопровождаемый, один. **Чай без ничего**. Суп без
>   ничего. Она была без ничего (голая).

Эти словари относят данное выражение к строгой литературной норме. Некоторые другие словари относят его к разговорному стилю, но я не смог найти ни одного словаря, в котором стояла бы помета *прост.* или *сниж*.

Comment: Очень интересно! Спасибо!

Comment: Я сам так не говорю, поэтому мне ближе Кузнецова (я к его трудам с осторожностью отношусь) и даже Ефремовой (у неё это с пометкой "разг.") словарная статья **Безо всего** из "Большого толкового словаря правильной русской речи; 8000 слов и выражений, Л. Скворцов, 2019" https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=kQO2DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=SDeozPE_yT&sig=ACfU3U3icowae69-eCcmzTil2foh_qCaiA&w=1280 _В современном нелитературном **просторечии** вместо "безо всего" употребляется неправильная конструкция "двойного отрицания": "без ничего" [без никого, без никаких]_

Comment: В примере из Лермонтова рассказ идет от имени _персонажа_, а у Щедрина, известного множеством неологизмов, это можно отнести к особенностям его свободного стиля.

Comment: @Alex_ander Вы не поняли. Я цитировал не писателей, а Большой академический словарь русского языка. А по поводу словарных предпочтений: я как-то я привёл цитату из этого словаря Л.Скворцова по вопросу "оплата за сверхурочный труд" — тогда я Вас не убедил :)

Comment: Я не о безоговорочном доверии к автору высказался, просто нашлась близкая точка зрения по конкретному вопросу. "Оплата за" (для меня) - в лучшем случае канцелярский жаргонизм.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам за комментарии, Александр и гризли!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ однозначный: форма не нормативна. Подробности - см. @ЕкатеринаКаштанова.

Пишу ради двух моментов.

~1. Не надо оправдывать сравнением с правильными вариантами конструкций с "ничего". Использование "ничего" требует отрицания (или частицей "нет", или "НЕ" при глаголе): "там нет ничего", "не ел ничего" и т. д., все остальное - ненормативно. Т. е. "без" таким отрицанием служить не может, и все аналоги с ним - ошибочны.

~2. Вопрос об использовании классиками. Очень кратко, хотя тут есть о чем поговорить, но нет сил. Может вернусь через какое-то время.
Понятно, что подобное не может служить аргументом нормативности. Уже потому, что автор просто не может иногда обойтись без передачи неправильностей речи героя. Ну представьте, что Настасья Филипповна вдруг заговорила бы языком, скажем, Бодлера?
А вот насколько соответствует речь героев Достоевского их социальному статусу - это вообще повод отдельного исследования. Настасья Филипповна - пусть и не высшего света дама, но никак не последняя простолюдинка. А говорит неправильно. Думаю, ответ дал Пушкин.

"Как уст румяных без улыбки,
Без грамматической ошибки
Я русской речи не люблю".
(Е. О.)

Comment: Спасибо большое, behemothus! Увидел, чей ответ я читаю, только прочитав. Думал, что ответ какой-то женщины почему-то. Интересны рассуждения насчёт Настасьи Филипповны, и спасибо за отрывок из Е. О. — очень любопытный, никогда не слышал (а когда читал, наверно, не обратил внимания)!

Comment: Что ж Вы меня по своему обычному правилу не поправили-то, когда я Н.Ф. по склерозу старческому **Натальей** Ф-ной назвал?! На запятые мне в общем-то наплевать, а вот такой ляп - это стыд и позор. )))

Comment: Я, честное слово, не заметил даже!)))